# How to Replace Text in Excel file based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a text in already existing excel sheet when a keyword is found , in the sample attached I am able to get the value & cell coordinates but the cell location is not in proper format to be used with sheetobj to replace value how can I get the proper cell coordinates

```
import openpyxl
path = "./BoldDemo.xlsx"

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

for values, rows in zip(sheet_obj.values, sheet_obj.rows):
    # print(values, rows)
    if "Hello" in values:
        print(rows)
        sheet_obj[rows] = "Hello test This is a Replace Text" # need asistance here
        wb_obj.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code.

```
import openpyxl
path = "./test.xlsx"

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

rows = sheet_obj.max_row
cols = sheet_obj.max_column

for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, cols + 1):
        if "Hello" in str(sheet_obj.cell(i, j).value):
            print(sheet_obj.cell(i, j).coordinate)
            sheet_obj.cell(i, j, value="Hello test This is a Replace Text")

wb_obj.save(path)
```

Comment: Welcome. Hope to be helpful for you.